# Codeigniter Query with Where with two arrays

Tags: php, codeigniter

hope you have good day.

I'm modifiying some code of Login function. It's in Codeigniter 3. So the username can be filled with email too.
How to write this code with Codeigniter?

Here's some code of my controller:

```
$data = array('username' => $this->input->post('username', TRUE),
            'password' => md5($this->input->post('password', TRUE))
        );

$data1 = array('email' => $this->input->post('username', TRUE),
            'password' => md5($this->input->post('password', TRUE))
        );

$this->load->model('m_login'); 
        $result= $this->m_login->cek_user($data, $data1);

        if ($result->num_rows() == 1) {
some code......
```

and here's the function of `cek_user()` in my Model:

```
public function cek_user($data, $data1) {
    $query = $this->db->get_where('mytable', $data||$data1);
    return $query;
}
```

all i want to ask is, how to use OR condition with array in `$data` anda `$data1`
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the codeigniter Manual, you can write your queries in below methods, 
Heres you can use where and or_where functions. You can find more on the below link.

[Link](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html)

**Method 1**

```
public function cek_user($data, $data1) {

            $where = "(name='$data[name]' AND password ='$data[password]') OR (email='$data1[email]' AND password ='$data[password]')";
            $this->db->where($where);
            $query = $this->db->get('my_table');
            return $query;

}
```

**Method 2**

```
public function cek_user($data, $data1) {

            $this->db->where($data);
            $this->db->or_where($data1); 
            $query = $this->db->get('my_table');
            return $query;
    $query = $this->db->get_where('mytable  ', $data||$data1);
    return $query;

}
```

Comment: your code worked pretty well. Thanks for that, yeah i know, we should take the variables inside array one by one to compared it with logic like OR AND, but i wonder if there's such simpler solution because i have already 2 array with the data, only to be "logic"-ed inside it. Like OR-ing `$data` and `$data1`. While the second method still gave me AND OR OR logic.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this in a single line of query

```
public function cek_user($data, $data1) {
    $this->db->where($data); $this->dB->or_where($data1);
   $query =  $this->db->get('mytable');
   return $query->result();
}
```

or your function should work like this

```
public function cek_user($data, $data1) {
   $query = $this->db->get_where('mytable', $data,$data1);
   return $query->result();
}
```

Hope it helps you out

Comment: thanks, the code compiled but when i tried to see the query, it shown
`SELECT * FROM 'daftar_keanggotaan WHERE 'username' = 'admin'` **AND**` 'password' = 'code'`** OR **`'email_rumah' = 'admin' `**OR** `'password' = 'code'` the logic is AND OR OR, while i want the logic be AND OR AND. any ideas? thanks

Comment: i am sorry. What i tried to explain is, the your code in cek_user($data, $data1) gave the query logic AND OR OR. The AND is from $data, the first OR is from OR in `or_where` and the the second OR is from $data1. While i want the logic is AND from $data OR from `or_where` and second AND from $data1. Thanks

Comment: Can you please write the query you need

Comment: SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE `username` = 'something' AND `password` = 'something' OR `email` = 'something' AND `password` = 'something`. The `$data1` anda `$data` should be AND. many thanks

Comment: it still give me query AND(from variables in `$data`) OR(from OR_WHERE) and OR(from variables in `$data1`). While what it supposed to be, the two variables in `$data1` should be AND-ed, so the query will be AND OR AND. I think, the problem comes from `OR_WHERE`. Anyway, thank you for your help, im gonna write another code to fix it later.

Answer (score 0):

In Your controller just put below code

```
$this->load->model('m_login'); 
$result= $this->m_login->cek_user($this->input->post());
if (!empty($result)) {
//Do Stuff
}
```

In Your Model

```
public function cek_user($postData) {
 $this->db->where('username', $postData['username']);
 $this->db->or_where('email', $postData['email']);
 $this->db->where('password', md5($postData['password']));
 $query = $this->db->get('mytable')->result();
 return $query;
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

try this :-

```
$username = $this->input->post('username', TRUE);
$password = $this->input->post('password', TRUE);

$where = "(`username`='$username' AND `password`='$password' or `email`='$username' AND `password`='$password')";
$this->db->where($where);
$query = $this->db->get('table');
return $query;
```